# RuntimeError: Not connected to CAN bus how to solve this one

Tags: python, can-bus, canopen

I am running this code on python to do the machine control through CANopen and CANbus but I am getting this error, please help me to solve this one.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "FW_CANopen_main_V1.1.py", line 718, in <module>
    initialisation()
  File "FW_CANopen_main_V1.1.py", line 35, in initialisation
    set_parameter()                                         # Parameter der INI Datei an FU schreiben
  File "FW_CANopen_main_V1.1.py", line 49, in set_parameter
    node2.sdo[0x202C].raw = L_SPEED_default * 10    # POSITION_speed_Y2; Faktor:10
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\canopen\common.py", line 90, in raw
    self.data = self.od.encode_raw(value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\canopen\common.py", line 42, in data
    self.set_data(data)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\canopen\sdo.py", line 265, in set_data
    self.sdo_node.download(self.index, self.subindex, data, force_segment)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\canopen\sdo.py", line 194, in download
    fp.close()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\canopen\sdo.py", line 528, in write
    response = self.sdo_client.request_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\canopen\sdo.py", line 120, in request_response
    self.send_request(sdo_request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\canopen\sdo.py", line 91, in send_request
    self.network.send_message(self.rx_cobid, request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\canopen\network.py", line 170, in send_message
    raise RuntimeError("Not connected to CAN bus")
RuntimeError: Not connected to CAN bus[
```

Comment: Sharing what you have done so far might be useful. Please see [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

For the USB to CAN adapter you are using, check its documentation to see how it is represented in Windows. And check the documentation for your library to see other examples of connecting to USB to CAN adapters. thanks